# TODAY() function with specified time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to get a date/time that represents the current day at 6:15 AM. The `TODAY()` function takes care of the date, but I can't figure out how to append the time constraint to that.

Usage will be in the form of:

```
IF(SOMEDATE <= TODAY@6:15AM, DoSomething(), DoSomethingElse())
```

Comment: `IF(SOMDATE <= TODAY() + TIME(6,15,0),...)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Dates in Excel are whole number and times are decimals based on the 24 hour cycle being 1 we can add the two together to get a number by which we can compare.

```
=TODAY() + TIME(6,15,0)
```

This will create a number equal to today at 6:15 this morning.

So incorporating that into your pseudo formula we get:

```
IF(SOMDATE <= TODAY() + TIME(6,15,0),...)
```